# Android java custom sorting using Comparable

Tags: java, android, sorting

```
  @Override
      public int compareTo(final myRow another) {

        final int BEFORE    =-1;
        final int EQUAL     = 0;
        final int AFTER     = 1;

        if (this==another) return EQUAL;

        if (sorttype==sort_type.SORT_ABC) {

            int rv      =0;
            int sorted  =row.toLowerCase().compareTo(another.getRow().toLowerCase());

            if (this.getUserType()==user_type.USER_TYPE_BANNED) rv=AFTER;
            if (this.getUserType()==user_type.USER_TYPE_NORMAL) rv=sorted;
            if (this.getUserType()==user_type.USER_TYPE_FRIEND) rv=BEFORE;

            Log.e("sorted", row+" "+this.getUserType()+" - "+rv+" ");

            return rv;

        } else if (sorttype==sort_type.SORT_LOGINTIME) {

            if (this.getUserType()==user_type.USER_TYPE_BANNED) {
                return AFTER;
            }
            if (this.getUserType()==user_type.USER_TYPE_NORMAL) return EQUAL;
            if (this.getUserType()==user_type.USER_TYPE_FRIEND) {
                //int sorted    =row.toLowerCase().compareTo(another.getRow().toLowerCase());
                return BEFORE;
            }

            //return 0;
        }

        return 0;

        //return row.toLowerCase().compareTo(another.getRow().toLowerCase());
      }
```

I have a String userlist, with nick names. I have banned users, normal users, and friend users.

I d like to sort my friend users to the top of the list, and the banned users to the bottom of the list, and I d like to showing them is ASC style.

How can i do that?

So the structure is:

```
Abc  (friend)
abrt (friend)
dfgh (friend)

abdfg (normal user)
bnmm  (normal user)
wert  (normal user)

Andgh  (banned user)
Dfghhj (banned user)
Qwer   (banned user)
```

I get this:

```
06-19 14:43:46.586: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(23434): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

Comment: Is the name of your class which contains this method `myRow`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks a bit complex. The simplest way would be to start from the highest priority field and move down to other fields. An example code would be:

```
public class Member implements Comparable<Member> {

    static enum Status {
        NORMAL(1), FRIEND(2), BANNED(3);

        private final int order;

        Status(int order) {
            this.order = order;
        }

        public int getOrder() {
            return this.order;
        }

    };

    private final String name;

    private final Status status;

    public Member(final String name, final Status status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Member o) {
        if (this.status.equals(o.status)) {
            return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
        } else {
            return this.status.compareTo(o.status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Member [name=" + name + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Member[] members = {
                        new Member("abrt", Status.FRIEND),
                        new Member("dfgh", Status.FRIEND),
                        new Member("abdf", Status.NORMAL),
                        new Member("wert", Status.NORMAL),
                        new Member("andgh", Status.BANNED),
                        new Member("qwer", Status.BANNED)
        };
        List<Member> lst = Arrays.asList(members);
        Collections.sort(lst);
        System.out.println(lst);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ABC sort logic doesn't work. If you pass in two `USER_TYPE_FRIEND` objects for instance, whatever their respective order, `compareTo` will always return `BEFORE`.

You need to implement this by first comparing the usertype.

If they are equal, you can return your `row.compareTo(...)` expression.

If not, you need to return before/after depending only on how those types "compare" in your logic (i.e. friend < normal < banned).

Answer (score 0):

my code now :

```
  public enum user_type {USER_TYPE_FRIEND(1), USER_TYPE_NORMAL(2), USER_TYPE_BANNED(3);
      private final int order;
      user_type(int order) {
          this.order = order;
      }
      public int getOrder() {
          return this.order;
      }
  }
```

...

```
  @Override
  public int compareTo(final myRow another) {

    if (sorttype==sort_type.SORT_ABC) {
        if (this.getUserType().equals(another.getUserType())) {
            return this.getRow().toLowerCase().compareTo(another.getRow().toLowerCase());
        } else {
            return this.getUserType().compareTo(another.getUserType());
        }
    } 
    else {
        //LOGINTIME
        return this.getUserType().compareTo(another.getUserType());
    }
  }
```

Thanks, Sanjay!

Comment: You are welcome. :) BTW, please follow the Java way of doing things and name your classes/enums/interfaces using camelcase (i.e. `UserType` instead of `user_type` or `MyRow` instead of `myRow`). Recommended reading: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html